# How to convert list to tree use recursion

Tags: c#, asp.net

we have a list need convert to tree.
data structure

```
public class node
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<node> child { get; set; }
}
```

for example:

```
var path = @"a\b\c\2017.log";
var filePath = path.Split('\\').ToList()
```

result need convert to：

```
"FileName":"a",
"Path":null,
"ChildNode":[{ 
              "FileName":"b",
               "Path":null,
               "ChildNode":[{
                              "FileName":"2017.log",
                              "Path":"a\b\\财务\2017.log",
                              "ChildNode"：null
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: And at least post correct text... *\财务* This doesn't exist in the *var path = @"..."*

Comment: Ah... More than a a tree structure it sees to be it a linked-list structure... Each parent has 0-1 children...

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static TreeNode GetTreeNode(DirectoryInfo d)
     {
         DirectoryInfo[] children = d.GetDirectories();
         FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles();
         IEnumerable<TreeNode> childNodes = from child in children select GetTreeNode(child);
         IEnumerable<TreeNode> fileNodes = from file in files select new TreeNode(file.Name, file.Path, null);
         return new TreeNode( d.Name, null, childNodes.Concat(fileNodes).ToList()); //Here we are merging directory list & File List
     }
```

//Composite

```
     class TreeNode
     {
         string name;
         string path;
         List<TreeNode> children;

         public TreeNode(string n, string p, List<TreeNode> cn)
         {
             this.name = n;
             this.path = p;
             this.children = cn;
         }
     }
```